# function template overloading - ordering

Tags: c++, function, templates

I don't get it. I know function templates are evil, but in this case we have to use it. So this is not the matter. We have an archive that uses a template-operator-function. The specialisation for objects/vale types follows after the template function declaration/definition:

```
class BaseArchive
{
public:
    BaseArchive() {}
    virtual ~BaseArchive();

    template< typename T >
    BaseArchive & operator<<(const T &t)
    {
        ::operator<<(*this, t);
        return *this;
    }
};

BaseArchive & operator<<(BaseArchive &ar, const int & i)
{
    return ar;
}

class StdArchive : public BaseArchive
{
public:
    StdArchive();

    template< typename T >
    StdArchive & operator<<(const T &t)
    {
        ::operator<<(*this, t);
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    BaseArchive ar;
    int i = 7;
    ar << i;
}
```

For this example we get an error:

**::operator<< has not been declared**

This one can be fixed by a forward declaration of

```
class BaseArchive;
BaseArchive & operator<<(BaseArchive &ar, const int & i);

class Archive { ...
```

So far so good. But afterwards some classes define their own ::operator for the archive and thus it hard or even not possible to ensure that the specific operator declaration occurs always before the archive-header-include nor even we want to use an global operator inlcude file.

Any idea how to solve this and/or a explanation why this error occurs? As usual the VS-compiler soesn't care about that, but the minGW (gcc) compiler does...

many thanks

Comment: Side note: I suggest a namespace for your code (avoid the global namespace)

Comment: of course we are using namespaces. This is just a simplified coed snippet ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why no freestanding operators and forwarding:

```
#include<iostream>

struct BaseArchive {};

BaseArchive & operator<<(BaseArchive &ar, const int & i)
{
    std::cout << "BaseArchive\n";
    return ar;
}

struct StdArchive : BaseArchive {};

template< typename T >
StdArchive& operator<<(StdArchive& archive, const T &t)
{
    std::cout << "StdArchive\n";
    operator << (static_cast<BaseArchive&>(archive), t);
    return archive;
}

int main()
{
    StdArchive ar;
    ar << 7;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First, function templates aren't evil. Where did you get that idea?

Second, your setup doesn't make sense. Why is the member function template `operator <<` there? It does nothing except forward to a global version, and because it uses explicit qualification, ADL doesn't apply.

Just remove the member function template and rely on ADL  to find the correct `operator<<`.